# Showing finite additivity of Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

I want to show that Lebesgue measure is finitely additive on the set of semi open rectangles of the form $[a,b)$ here is what I did ($\sqcup$ is disjoint union , $\lambda^n$ is n-dimensional Lebesgue measure):

Let $I=[a_1,b_1)\times \ldots\times[a_n,b_n)$, then $I$ can be cut into disjoint pieces $I_1=[a_1,b_1)\times \ldots\times[a_n,c)$ , $I_2=[a_1,b_1)\times \ldots\times[c,b_n)$ where $a_n<c<b_n$ and $I_1 \sqcup I_2=I$, $$\lambda^n(I_1)+\lambda^n(I_2)=(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_1)\ldots(c-a_n)+(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_1)\ldots(b_n-c)=(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_1)\ldots(b_n-c+c-a_n)=(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_1)\ldots(b_n-a_n)=\lambda^n(I)$$

Is this right (If not how can it be fixed or it isn't going to work)(Would induction on $n$ work?)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here.  Are you trying to show that $\lambda^{n}$ is finitely additive for all $n$?  If so, the induction idea is a good way to go, but you should make a clearer use of the induction hypothesis. 

More generally, what do you mean by "finitely additive on the set of semi open rectangles"?  Normally, for some notion of finite additivity to work, you need to be working in a field, but since the union of rectangles is not generally a rectangle, you aren't.

Comment: @Unwisdom I should have been more specific, I'm trying to show if $I_1$ and $I_2$ are two disjoint semi open rectangles whose union remains a semi open rectangle $I$ then $\lambda^n(I_1 \cup I_2)=\lambda^n(I)$ . I couldn't find a way using induction I'd always get stuck.